how to automatically enable a button without clicking on it?
i want the first button to be clicked right when the page loads im building it using html,css, typescript
<div class="media-column">
 <!-- posts button -->
    <button #postsButton class="media-button"(click)="applyFilter('posts')">
      <span class="media-label">Posts</span>
    </button>
  <!-- images button -->
    <button class="media-button"(click)="applyFilter('images')">
      <span class="media-label">Pictures</span>
    </button>
 <!-- videos button -->
  <button class="media-button" (click)="applyFilter('videos')">
      <span class="media-label">Videos</span>
    </button>
  </div>

i tried but it didnt work, i didnt getthe button clicked
 @ViewChild('postsButton', { static: true }) postsButton!: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {   
      this.postsButton.nativeElement.click();
  }


You should simply call the button click function applyFilter, without clicking it programatically, it does the same thing.
ngOnInit() {   
    this.applyFilter('posts');
}


When ngOnInit() is called, the template is not rendered yet. You need to use ngAfterViewInit() instead.
@ViewChild('postsButton', { static: true }) postsButton!: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {   
  this.postsButton.nativeElement.click();
}

For more information about the component lifecycle, check the docs.

i tried it also didnt work, the button is not clicked
